# In Sitecore Webforms for Marketers how can I choose an existing form instead of always creating a new form?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore7.5

I'm using Sitecore 7.5 and Webforms for Marketers 2.5. I am trying to add a form to a page in the Presentation details.  Is there any way that I can choose an already existing form?  It seems like Sitecore only allows you to copy an existing form which then creates a new form.  I don't want to create a new form, I want to insert an already existing form.

In addition I have the same problem when trying to use the Personalization options for a form.  I want to use Personalization and present the user with a different form based on some custom rules.  However every time I try to do the Personalization wizard it always forces me to create a new form.  I don't want to add a new form, I want to pick an existing one.  Very odd.

[image]

Comment: This is a known shortcoming. I have raised it with Sitecore in the past and it doesn't seem to be possible without some reworking of the module.